# Multiple sliders on same page by binding a jquery slider to ajax loaded images

Tags: jquery, html

Need Some Jquery Help.

I want to use http://www.basic-slider.com/ on my page. I have infinite scroll, which adds new images. Some are a set of images, so I would like to add a slider for those sets. It looks like this.

```
<ul class="images">
   <li id="1">  <img1>
                <img2>
                <img3> </li>
   <li id="2"> 
                <img1></li>
   <li id="3">
                <img2>
                <img3> </li>
.
.
<ul>
```

infinite load will add more `<li>` to `.images` via ajax. I can make html changes such as putting images inside another `<ul>` but not sure how to change the jquery code.

Please help.

Comment: Are you using a plugin for your infinite scroll?

Comment: @SajunaFernando well no. I just use jquery and check "closetoBottom" and load more

Comment: @SajunaFernando 

function onScroll(event) {
        // Check if we're within 1500 pixels of the bottom edge of the broser window.
       var closeToBottom = ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 1500);
        
        if(closeToBottom) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you can do something like this.

```
var imageBlock = 0; //THIS IS GLOBAL
```

then create a function which initializes the slider plugin

```
function initializeSlider(imageBlock){
    $('#images' + imageBlock).bjqs({
      'height' : 320,
      'width' : 620,
      'responsive' : true
    });
 }
```

Then as you scroll if closeToBottom

```
if(closeToBottom){
  imageBlock = imageBlock + 1;
  initializeSlider(imageBlock);
}
```

You can do the same on page load as well.

Note: Add the the ul elements you create with an incrementing index.